# How to serve React app with Material-UI and react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, material-ui

I developed an application with this major components React + Material-UI + react-router. Here is my full `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "trader-ui",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.2.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.1",
    "@stomp/stompjs": "^5.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "^16.5.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "2.0.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8080"
}
```

It works just fine on the development server:

```
$ npm start
```

Here it is:

[image]

However, when I tried to serve a production build:

```
$ npm run build
$ npm install -g serve
$ serve -s build
```

It looks:

[image]

Could somebody tell me what went wrong with the production build?

Comment: Do you see any errors if you check the Network tab of your Developer Tools?

Comment: check if this helps: https://material-ui.com/getting-started/faq/#why-aren--39-t-my-components-rendering-correctly-in-production-builds-

Comment: @Tholle, no errors

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @giorgim for his suggestion. It was correct. Use Material-UI FAQ to resolve the issue:

> https://material-ui.com/getting-started/faq/#why-aren--39-t-my-components-rendering-correctly-in-production-builds-

My code for styles setup was in `withRoot.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import {createMuiTheme, MuiThemeProvider} from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
    typography: {
        useNextVariants: true,
    },
});

function withRoot(Component) {
  function WithRoot(props) {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <Component {...props} />
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }

  return WithRoot;
}

export default withRoot;
```

I simply wrapped my components with `JssProvider`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { create } from 'jss';
import JssProvider from 'react-jss/lib/JssProvider';
import {
    MuiThemeProvider,
    createMuiTheme,
    createGenerateClassName,
    jssPreset,
} from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
    typography: {
        useNextVariants: true,
    },
});

const jss = create(jssPreset());
const generateClassName = createGenerateClassName();

function withRoot(Component) {
  function WithRoot(props) {
    return (
        <JssProvider jss={jss} generateClassName={generateClassName}>
            <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                <CssBaseline />
                <Component {...props} />
            </MuiThemeProvider>
        </JssProvider>
    );
  }

  return WithRoot;
}

export default withRoot;
```

Of course you should install `react-jss` beforehand:

```
$ npm install react-jss
```